# javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(String address) throws NPE (Java 8u162 )

Tags: java, java-8

After upgrading java from 8u151 to 8u162, it started to throw NPE in `javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(String address)`. With 8u151 everything was fine and now it publishes only one (the first) endpoint at the provided server context, on the second get NPE (see logs below). I suppose something is wrong with ServerMgr implementation (can not find sources to ensure). Any help will be appreciated.

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException at
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:130) ~ [?:1.8.0_162] at
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish (HttpEndpoint.java:64) ~
[?:1.8.0_162] at
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish
(EndpointImpl.java:232) ~ [?:1.8.0_162]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After investigations found that http Jetty shared server causes problems. That one seems is not compatible with latest java 8 versions (8u152, 8u161, 8u162).

Comment: Would you or anyone else have any updated regarding this? Tried with the latest jetty (9.4.11 20180605) as well and jdk 8u172 still the same. I thought this was the problem in jetty and fixed in 9.4.9: 
 + 2114 Fix NPE in JettyHttpServerProvider


https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2114

Comment: Looks like a fix for jetty and a fix in jdk for different things together causes this to me. If only one of the fixes are there it's fine it seems. Jdk fix in 8u152: I 8u152
https://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8146086
Added a getAddress and jetty added so it can be delayed bind so returns null until later. Filed issue with jetty for now: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2718

Answer (score 0):

@MattiasIsegranBergander the workaround for me was to publish endpoints at the provided server contexts. Ex:

```
    Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING, webService);
    try {
        JettyHttpServerProvider.setServer(server);
        HttpContext context = new JettyHttpServerProvider().createHttpServer(new InetSocketAddress(port), 5)
                .createContext("/" + serviceName);
        endpoint.publish(context);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
```

Also wanted the fix for this was added in jetty library in 9.4.x versions (https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2718). Good work @MattiasIsegranBergander.